# originatingactivityid is not set in a Campaign Response record

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

When I do the action **Convert To > Promote To Response** on a Phone Call Activity a new record of type **Campaign Response** is created.

This new record has a field **originatingactivityid** - which I suppose should be populated with the phonecall that I performed the action on, but it isn't.

How does the originatingactivityid work and **how can I populate it**?

Are there any ways to do it without any development ?

If no, have you deals with this issue before, with a plugin and what was your experience like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved with just simply adding 'Originating Activity' field to the main form of the Campaign Response. I don't know why it wasn't existing on the form.